# Cannot access jQuery when appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I append a button via jQuery.

```
$('#toAppend').html('<input type="button" id="helloWorld">');
```

In my browser, I can see the button but I am not able to access it via jQuery.

Code:

```
$('#helloWorld').click(function () {
    alert("you clicked me");
})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: try this: `$(...).on("click", function(){...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) like this for [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/):

```
$(document).on('click', '#helloWorld', function () {
  alert("you clicked me");
})
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I spend with this almost the whole day

Answer (score 2):

You have to access it in a different manner because it was appended to html after the page was loaded:

```
$("#toAppend").on("click", "button#helloWorld", function(e) {
    console.log("clicked!");
});
```